# angularjs app running on localhost but not on heroku

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku

My angularjs app is running perfectly fine on localhost on my machine. But when I deploy it to heroku, the app is showing up but some of the features, mainly the frontend to backend communication is failing. I suspect that this is because I have used `http://localhost:3000` instead of my real website addess: `https://mytestapp.herokuapp.com` . Could somebody please let me know what I should do to get this app running on heroku? with backend communicating with the frontend to get the login/signup feature running. At the moment, when I login or signup, I get an error, as if nothing has happened.

I ran `grunt build`, and removed the `/dist` from `.gitignore` and have a **procfile** like this `web: node api.js` .

and my package.json file is like:

```
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nf start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

I have also declared a constant in my app.config.js like:

```
  .constant('API_URL', 'http://localhost:3000/')
```

I use `API_URL` to setup my login/signup authproviders.

and in my gruntfile.js , I have the following bit as well:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect().use(
            '/app/styles',
            connect.static('./app/styles')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      port: 9001,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect.static('test'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
```

### update

i am trying to implement it in this controller, but no success:
when I implement the Yoni's solution, i don't get the `projectlist` anymore, it shows an empty page. why is that?

```
'use strict';
angular.module('ModuleV11App')
  .controller('ProjectlistCtrl', function ($http, $scope, API_URL, alert) {
    return $http.get($rootScope.server.url + '/projectlist').success(function (projectlist) {
      $scope.projectlist = projectlist;
    }).error(function (err) {
      alert('warning', "Unable to get projects, please login first", err.message);
    })

  });
```

however, it works, when it is like this:

```
return $http.get(API_URL + 'projectlist').success(function (projectlist) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [$location service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location).

You can do something like this:

```
angular.module('mainModule', [])
    .run(function($location,$rootScope) {
        $rootScope.server = {url: location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + (location.port ? ':' + location.port : '')};
    })
```

Then you can have calls like this anywhere in your frontend code:

```
$http.get($rootScope.server.url + '/whatever');
```

Comment: In your angular app,js (or whatever you call the file your ng-app module is in).

Comment: my app.js is like: 
`'use strict';
angular
  .module('loginMdouleV11App', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'satellizer']);`

you mean here?

Comment: i updated my question, i need your help to clarify this issue, thanks

Comment: You need to add the .run function I posted above in your module:
angular.module('ModuleV11App')

Comment: you mean in every angular.module? not in my app.js only? in others as well?

Comment: You only need it in your main app.js. Just add the .run function that I posted above.

Comment: as i explained above, i implemented it in main app.js and replaced the old API_URLs with your suggested code. Other controllers work, but the bit of code I have posted as an update doesn't work. it doesn't show the `projectlist` anymore. why is that?